# What is the "correct" way to render to a cubemap using Vulkan?

Tags: 3d, graphics-programming, vulkan

After searching far and wide for the solution to this, the only one I have been able to find that verifiably works is to the render a face to a framebuffer and then use a memcpy to copy that framebuffer over to the respective part of the cubemap image.

This sounds stupid.

So I ask: Surely there must be some way to render directly to one face of a cubemap image, seeing as it's such an important feature in a whole lot of 3D rendering techniques. **How do you do it?**

Comment: So I'm not well versed in Vulkan ( actually not at all )  but wouldn't you handle a cubemap trough a shader [like so](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/60313/implementing-a-skybox-with-glsl-version-330)? Doing some googling Vulkan takes pure Spir-V instead of GLSL? 

You can convert GLSL to SPIR-V i think
You might want to look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the Vulkan specification that prevents you from using an image of a cubemap texture as a color attachment image in a `VkFramebuffer` in a render pass instance. So you would simply do that: create a cubemap image, and use it in the framebuffer of a render pass instance.